# Can I parse XML in Java without taking XML file input from outside?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Generally using DOM, SAX or XPath etc parser we do take input from outside Java code like this:

```
File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\catalog.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
```

So can you parse XML file without taking input like this? I want to write my XML code alongside Java code.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can store an XML file in your classpath? If so, yes, you can. If you're using Maven, put the file in `src/main/rresources/your/path/goes/here.xml` and access it via `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/your/path/goes/here.xml"`.

Comment: @SeverityOne this has nothing to do with maven. I think he is asking if he can embed the XML string into his code (for some unknown reason).  *The answer is yes * and a vote for close as SO is not made to suggest tutorials.

Comment: @zyexal The way I interpret his question, and considering that English is probably not his first question, he has some sort of configuration file that he wants to embed with his code. The Maven example is there, because a lot of people use Maven. He could be using sbt for all I know.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DocumentBuilder.parse(new InputStream(new StringReader(xml)))` where xml is a string containing the XML to be parsed.

That's if you really must use DOM. I can't imagine why anyone uses it any more, when alternatives such as JDOM2 are so much better.

Comment: You should always balance pros and cons wether to use a third party library or stick to the standard. How future-proof is JDOM2? Will it still be maintained in five years? Or in ten?

Comment: Yes, you need to assess technology and there are sometimes reasons for not choosing the best. But most people are choosing DOM because they know no better: by historical accident DOM made it into the JDK before anyone realised quite how awful it is, and once in, there's no chance of changing it.